# Let $p,q$ be two distinct prime numbers. For a group $G$ with order $pq$, which one are correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $p,q$ be two distinct prime numbers. For a group $G$ with order $pq$, which one are correct?
>
> (A) $G$ has four subgroups
>
> (B) $G$ is Abelian
>
> (C) $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{pq}$, where $S_n$ is the permutation group of $n$ numbers.

First, by Sylow Theorem, there are at least four subgroups: $\emptyset$, $G$, a group with order $p$, and a group with order $q$. But Sylow Theorem doesn't tell us that there exists a unique subgroup of every factor of $|G|$. Therefore I am not sure if (A) is correct.

Then for (B), we can let $p=2,q=3$ and then $|G|=6$. The dihedral group with order $6$ is not Abelian. But if $p,q \neq 2$, is (B) correct?

For (C), I know that by Cayley's theorem, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last is correct.

Dihedral groups also give counterexamples to A. In general Sylow-p subgroups are not unique unless you're talking about isomorphism classes rather than number - though if p is the larger prime in a group of order pq it will be. (There *are* four isomorphism classes of subgroup for each group of order $pq$; the one of order $pq$ can be different for different groups.)

If say $p|q-1$ then you get a non abelian semidirect product - 2 is not special in this respect. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product).

Answer (score 0):

One technical detail to note--the definition of a group requires you have an identity element, so $\emptyset$ is not a group. However, the trivial group, the group with one element, is. On the other hand, I would check $S_3$, the permutation group on three elements, to see if statement (A) is true.

Also, there are dihedral groups of order $2n$ for any $n > 1$. In particular, if $n = 5$, $D_{10}$ is a nonabelian group. (This may go without saying too, but if a statement is false for *any* possible value of the variables, it is automatically false.)